# wifi router with easily configurable firewall

Tags: wifi, router, firewall

I need a router for our family. Our internet provider installed a compal-ch7465lg router which works fine but the firewall in it is not enough advanced.

The most important thing is that I would like to restrict access per device (mac address) per url (for example wikipedia, spotify, etc.) per daytime.

For example, for a given device (given mac address) I want to allow everything between 16:00 and 18:00, only allow spotify and wikipedia between 8:00 and 16:00 and between 18:00 and 21:00 and disallow everything between 21:00 and 08:00.

Ideally a layman (for example my wife) should be able to configure the firewall.

Do you have recommendations for this?

Comment: That's pretty tricky. I think the easiest way to do that is to set up the devices to clear the DNS cache every 5 minutes (using crontab or something like that) and then set up a pihole